# Scheme - How to return the intersection of an INFINITE amount of sets?

Tags: set, scheme, intersection, infinite

I am trying to write a function that will work for an infinite amount of sets instead of just the normal intersection function that only takes two sets. I have however written a normal intersection function (that takes only 2 sets) that looks like this:

```
(define intersection
 (lambda (s1 s2 [res '()])
  (cond ((set-empty? s1) (make-set res))
        ((member? (set-first s1) s2) (intersection (set-rest s1) s2 (set-insert (set-first s1) res)))
        (else (intersection (set-rest s1) s2 res)))))
```

I have a broken intersection function that attempts to take an infinite amount of sets as arguments called "intersection*". It currently looks like this:

```
(define intersection*
 (lambda (s1 s2 . r)
  (cond ((set-empty? r) (intersection s1 s2))
        (else (intersection s1 (apply append s2 r))))))
```

Where the argument 'r' is a rest argument.

However I did manage to write a Union function that takes an infinite amount of sets:

```
(define union*
 (lambda (s1 [s2 '()] . r)
  (cond ((set-empty? r) (union s1 s2))
        (else (union s1 (apply append s2 r))))))
```

You might notice that the union* function and the intersection* function look almost identical. Thats because I tried to desperately use the same logic on the intersection* function as in the union* function. I didn't expect it to work either... I am just running out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: Arbitrarily many is not the same as infinitely many.

Comment: As soon as you use append on sets implemented as lists, you potentially break the property that elements occur only once in a set. Union and intersection might not behave as expected. Here you are appending sets, which sort of works for unions, but this makes no sense for the intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `intersection` is correctly implemented, you just have to intersect the first two sets together, then the result of that with the next set, and the next, and so on. This should work:

```
(define (intersect* s1 s2 . r)
  (foldl intersect (intersect s1 s2) r))
```

The above is the same as:

```
(define (intersect* s1 s2 . r)
  (let helper ((acc (intersect s1 s2)) (r r))
    (if (null? r)
        acc
        (helper (intersect (first r) acc) (rest r)))))
```

Bonus: this version short-circuits and as soon as it finds an empty intersection, returns:

```
(define (intersect* s1 s2 . r)
  (let helper ((acc (intersect s1 s2)) (r r))
    (cond ((null? r) acc)
          ((null? acc) '())
          (else (helper (intersect (first r) acc) (rest r))))))
```

Comment: Couln't this be done short circuiting. eg. the second `acc` is the empty set you can stop since you have the result?

Comment: Not with a `fold` operation... continuation-based solution left as an exercise for the reader :P

Comment: But the roll your own  `intersect*` could easily do it.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Thanks! It worked like a charm. For some reason I was so focused on solving this with 'map' that the though of using 'fold' never even crossed my mind. You're a lifesaver ;)